# Flairs are not visible in https://askubuntu.com/election

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flair

The flairs of the moderators are not visible in https://askubuntu.com/election. Refer this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of https://askubuntu.com/election in Firefox]

When I try to open image in new tab in Firefox, it's completely blank:

[image: Screenshot of https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/264781.png in Firefox]

When I try to open image in new tab in Chrome, there's an error:

[image: Screenshot of https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/264781.png in Chrome]

> ### This page isn’t working
>
> **askubuntu.com** is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

I tried in both Firefox (version 89.0.2) and Chrome (Version 91.0.4472.114). Looks like this is a bug. Please fix it.

Comment: I have the same issue on Firefox on Android and Chrome on Android. Don't have a desktop/laptop nearby to test at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking this as norepro, as it looks like the problem has resolved on its own (caching issue? errant server rebuilt?). If anyone sees this again, please let me know.